# gcc undefined reference with local created Objects

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I am new in c++ , I use GCC compiles under windows when I create any local object the compiler issue the error message "undefined local reference"
I want to create factory function like the code below
error message :"undefined reference to `Widget::Widget()'"

```
class Widget
{
    public:
        Widget();
        virtual ~Widget();
        int data() { return data_; }
        void setData(int val) { data_ = val; }
    protected:
    private:
         int data_;
};

Widget* createWidget()
{
    Widget* w = new Widget();
    return w;
}
int callSomething(Widget* widget,Signal* sig,int x)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    callSomething(createWidget(),createSignal(),4);
}
```

Comment: `createSignal()` is defined where actually?

Comment: Please include the actual error message.

Comment: Post the complete error message along with the actual code it refers to.

Comment: Error message:undefined reference to `Widget::Widget()'|

Comment: Well, OK, where is Widget constructor?

Comment: really it is part of complete code constructor implemented in cpp file

Answer (score 1):

`undefined reference to x` is telling you that you haven't defined function `x` but you're trying to call it. And the compiler is right:

You haven't defined your `Widget` constructor.

Replace `Widget();` with `Widget() {}` if you just want an empty constructor, or remove `Widget();` if you don't need an user-defined constructor.

Comment: thank you @zenith but it is just a part of the complete code the constructor is implemented in cpp file

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I really use ,CodeBlocks with GCC compiler , problem come from the environment when I close the editor then open the same project then  compile It compile successfully ,I don't know what happen ,
 thank you for every body